# How to disable popup "login with google" in macOS Chrome app without extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-identity

On many websites there is enabled the one-tap or Google [YOLO (You Only Login Once)](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview?hl=en).

I need an option to disable this popup. I don't like that a website sees my Google account credentials in a popup.

Is this possible without an additional extension in Google Chrome?